# What are these region codes for firmware files?

Tags: language

In particular I am looking at old firmware files for a 2005? mp3 player, the iRiver T30.

I am seeing obvious region/languages such as ENG (English), KOR (Korean), FRE (French), JAP (Japanese) but I am curious about the following

- LAT
- CNS
- EST

Answer (score 2):

CNS - Traditional Chinese
EST - Estonian
LAT - Latvian

You can use [this site](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/langcodes-search.php) to check 3-letter language codes (ISO 639-2)

Comment: I did consider all those, but a korean made mp3 player having those 2 european languages seemed a bit odd.

thanks. :)

Comment: @watermelon, check my updated answer.